# Can't get pivot_wider values_fn to use multiple functions

Tags: pivot

I'm trying to use the values_fn argument in pivot_wider to apply a function to specific columns when there are multiple values. Using the iris dataset as an example:

```
iris.long <- iris %>% 
   mutate(seq = rep(1:75, each = 2)) %>% 
   select(-Petal.Length, -Petal.Width) %>% 
   pivot_longer(-c("Species", "seq"), names_to = "Name", values_to = "Value")

> print(iris.long)
# A tibble: 300 x 4
   Species   seq Name         Value
   <fct>   <int> <chr>        <dbl>
 1 setosa      1 Sepal.Length   5.1
 2 setosa      1 Sepal.Width    3.5
 3 setosa      1 Sepal.Length   4.9
 4 setosa      1 Sepal.Width    3  
 5 setosa      2 Sepal.Length   4.7
 6 setosa      2 Sepal.Width    3.2
 7 setosa      2 Sepal.Length   4.6
 8 setosa      2 Sepal.Width    3.1
 9 setosa      3 Sepal.Length   5  
10 setosa      3 Sepal.Width    3.6
# ... with 290 more rows
```

Now when I try to use a named list for `values_fn`, it still gives me col-list output and instead of aggregating the multiple values:

```
iris.long %>% 
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c("Species", "seq"), names_from = "Name", values_from = "Value", 
               values_fn = list(Sepal.Length = mean, Sepal.Width = min))

# A tibble: 75 x 4
   Species   seq Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
   <fct>   <int> <list>       <list>     
 1 setosa      1 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 2 setosa      2 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 3 setosa      3 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 4 setosa      4 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 5 setosa      5 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 6 setosa      6 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 7 setosa      7 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 8 setosa      8 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
 9 setosa      9 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
10 setosa     10 <dbl [2]>    <dbl [2]>  
# ... with 65 more rows
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates
```

Can anyone help, please? Much appreciated.